# how to select divs with jquery like for example in photoshop ? (select area)

Tags: jquery, html, select, area

I have some divs, on some positions. I want to select them with mouse, like when are you selecting object in photoshop. So I want to select group of divs. is that possible with jquery?

Comment: Do you mean something like a drag-select? Like dragging a box around several objects, which will then mark all contained objects as selected?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i mean.. is that possible with jquery ?

Answer (score 3):

There's [jQuery Drag to Select](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/drag-to-select/), which will probably solve your problems.

Comment: have problems to work with it, somebody know how run that example which is on that site ?

Comment: anyway, does somebody know, how to use it with divs ?   it works only with ul and li ? thanks

Comment: As far as I can see from the examples, you'll need to do this: `$('#parent-element').dragToSelect(selectables: 'div')`, but I can't be 100% sure... Hold on.

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. If you want to make more types of elements selectable, comma-separate them: `div, li, tr` (the plugin inserts this string straight into a jQuery, so you could use virtually any supported CSS3-selector =D )

Comment: Note that you must add curly braces : "{selectables: 'div'}"

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a selected effect by changing the classes of the divs, e.g.:

```
$('div.selectable').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('.selected');
});
```

If you want the div to get unselected after is has been clicked again, you can do something like:

```
$('div.selectable').click(function() {
    if($(this).is('.selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('.selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('.selected');
    }
});
```

or more concisely with the ternary operator:

```
$('div.selectable').click(function() {
    var $div = $(this);
    $div.is('.selected') ? $div.removeClass('.selected') : $div.addClass('.selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) plugin as the base of your code.